# What are the best techniques to perform text simplification?

Tags: natural-language-processing, python, text-summarization

I'm evaluating the state of the art techniques to translate legal text to simple text, what are the best approaches for a non-English language (Portuguese)?

Comment: Maybe you should explain more in detail what you mean by "text simplification" or "simple text".